# Deploy Action when Reducer Field is Null

Tags: reactjs, redux

Let's say I have an auth reducer which holds information about the current user. What's the best way to automatically deploy a `populateUser()` action when the auth reducer is null, but I have a valid jwt in local storage?

Comment: What do you mean by `the auth reducer is null`? Did you mean the current user in the auth reducer is null?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: And do you really need to execute this action at any time? Isn't executing it when the page loads enough?

Comment: I guess what I really want is whenever the route changes.

Comment: Can you edit your answer? Add some more details (are you using react-router?) and the source code of the key parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using React-Router, you could use the "onEnter" hook to send an ajax request to a backend route that checks the request header for the token every time a route change occurs.  The server then sends back the associated user data, which allows the state to be updated. The following code assumes use of react-redux, redux-thunk middleware, and axios for api requests.

```js
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={App} onEnter={checkAuth }>      
        < children..../>
    </Route>
  </Router>
</Provider>
      
function checkAuth(){
  store.dispatch(authenticate())   
}     

function authenticate() {
  return function (dispatch) {
     axios.get('/api/auth/')
     .then(user => {
         dispatch(populateUser(user))
       }
    }
 }
```